# How to print Comma Separated Values into an object?

Tags: javascript

I have some Comma Separated Values (CSV) data:

```
const thingsToDo =
```

`name,location
Notre Dame,Paris
louver museum, Paris
Botanical Garden,Montreal
The Alamo, San Antonio
Colosseum,Rome
Eiffel Tower, Paris`

I need to write a function that outputs something like this:

```
  {
  Paris: [' Notre Dame ',' louver museum ', ' Eiffel Tower '],
  Montreal: [' Botanical Garden '],
  San Antonio: [' The Alamo '],
  Rome: [' Colosseum ']
}
```

The values should be sorted alphabetically.

```
Paris:[' Eiffel Tower ',' louver museum ',' Notre Dame ']
```

So far I did this but i don't know how to print out the exact output like that:

```
const Paris = ['Notre Dame','louver museum','Eiffel Tower'];
const commaSeparated1 = Paris.filter(item => item).join(', ');
const Montreal = ['Botanical Garden'];
const commaSeparated2 = Montreal.filter(item => item).join(', ');
const SanAntonio = ['The Alamo'];
const commaSeparated3 = SanAntonio.filter(item => item).join(', ');
const Rome = ['Colosseum'];
const commaSeparated4 = Rome.filter(item => item).join(', ');

console.log(commaSeparated1);
console.log(commaSeparated2);
console.log(commaSeparated3);
console.log(commaSeparated4);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Seblor 

`const Paris = ['Notre Dame','louver museum','Eiffel Tower'];
const commaSeparated1 = Paris.filter(item => item).join(', ');
const Montreal = ['Botanical Garden'];
const commaSeparated2 = Montreal.filter(item => item).join(', ');
const SanAntonio = ['The Alamo'];
const commaSeparated3 = SanAntonio.filter(item => item).join(', ');
const Rome = ['Colosseum'];
const commaSeparated4 = Rome.filter(item => item).join(', ');

console.log(commaSeparated1);
console.log(commaSeparated2);
console.log(commaSeparated3);
console.log(commaSeparated4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function process(csv) {
  const obj = {}
  for(const line of csv.split(/\r?\n/g)) {
    const [name, location] = line.split(",")
    obj[location.trim()] = [ ...(obj[location.trim()] || []), name.trim() ]
  }
  return obj
}


const csv = 
`Notre Dame,Paris
louver museum, Paris
Botanical Garden,Montreal
The Alamo, San Antonio
Colosseum,Rome
Eiffel Tower, Paris`

console.log(process(csv))
```

Comment: Then sort arrays if you need